# Batch file to output file name from variable

Tags: file, batch-file

I am trying to assign a file name from the variable which has been previously given by the user. How can I do it? I am a bit stuck with my code (attached below) Could you please give me some advice?

```
@ECHO OFF
CLS
mode con:cols=90 lines=30
SET /P name="Please enter name: "  &:: Asking for name and store it as name
mkdir "C:\%name%"&ECHO Dump folder created 
ECHO.
TIMEOUT /T 3 /nobreak>NUL                                         
SET /P decision="Do you want to run all modules? Y-Yes N-No"   &:: Decision to execute all modules or just one
    IF %decision%==y (GoTo Full) 
    ELSE IF %decision%==Y (Goto Full)
    ELSE IF(GoTo Basic)                               
            :Full 
            >C:\%name%\%DATE:~-4%-%DATE:~4,2%-%DATE:~7,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%.txt 
            @ECHO OFF
[some commands]
            GoTo End
            :Basic
             ECHO "WORKING?"   &::This bit need to be completed lol
             GoTo End
:End                        
                TIMEOUT /T 5
```

Comment: You should open a Command Prompt window, type `if /?` and press the `ENTER` key to learn the correct syntax. 1. `If /I "%decision%" == "y" (GoTo Full`, 2. `) ELSE GoTo Basic`, or just one line, `If /I "%decision%" == "y" (GoTo Full) ELSE GoTo Basic`, or even another two liner, 1. `If /I "%decision%" == "y" (GoTo Full`, 2. `GoTo Basic`. However all that said, you are using the wrong command, _(`Set /P`)_. Please open a Command Prompt window, type `choice /?` and press the `ENTER` key to learn the correct syntax for the appropriate command, (e.g. `choice.exe /M "Do you want to run all modules"`)

Comment: Hello :-) Thank you for your answers! The reason why I dont want to check that directory exist is because it will be used only once at the pc and then this file should be deleted. I am still struggle to get output from the commands saved to the file in specific directory.

Answer (score 0):

I am a little confused as to what you are trying to do. I think that you want to create a directory and then put a file in the directory. If I wanted to create a file and put it in a folder that has the same name, I would do

```
set /p %name%=
mkdir C:\%name%
(
echo Works!
)>C:\%name%\%name%.txt
```

Hope this helps.